# Can't get eclipse to recognize my plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I exported my eclipse plugin through the "Export Wizard" in the manifest and seems like everything went well (no errors). It created a .jar file within a plugin directory in a zip file.

I thought putting the jar into my Eclipse plugin directory would install it (after re-launching eclipse) but that didn't work. Eclipse can't see the plugin (the perspective isn't showing up)

I tried with Help->Install new software->local archive but it keeps saying "no software found"

Can you help me getting my plugin ready to be installed on a fresh Eclipse copy?

Ps. my plugin uses other dependencies like EMF/GMF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In eclipse, go to your console window. From the drop down meny, select OSGI console. Run the command `ss` or `ss <name of your plugin>`
You will then see the state of your plugin and a number. The state will probably be "installed" which means if has been found, but some dependencies were not satisfied.

Run the command `diag <number of your plugin>` and you will see why it wasn't started.

For more details, see [Wheres my bundle](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle)

**Edit:** A first step to verify that the plugin is working would be to start up a new eclipse instance with your plugin. In the run configuration dialog, there is a tab with all the plugins that should be started. Make sure yours is checked and it will start with the new eclipse instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse 3.4 or above, put your plugin in the 'dropins' directory.

To install via Help->Install new software you need to create an 'Update site' or a 'p2 repository'.

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't know why but I can't see the plugin appearing

Comment: `create an 'Update site' or a 'p2 repository'.` - can u pls tell how ?

Answer (score 1):

By far the most ellaborate descriptions of installing your plugin is provided by Vogella [deployment of your plug-in](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#p2deployplugin)

It covers all 3 possible ways in which you may install your plugin detailing the pros & cons of each of the following approaches :

1 . Installing your plug-in from your Eclipse IDE

2 . Export plug-in and put into dropins folder

3 . Create update site for your plug-in

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to restart Eclipse. File -> Restart and try again. Worked for me because Eclipse was caching the results of my local update site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open plugin.xml
2. In "Overview" Tab in "Exporting section" go to "Export Wizard"
3. In "Export" window in "Destination" section choose "Install into host. Repository" and choose dir which will looks like "xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/install/"
4. Press "Finish" button
5. Wait for Export to finish without any problems
6. Restart Eclipse