# Exported plug-in is not loaded when starting Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I wrote a plug-in in Eclipse and exported it. It works fine and is loaded when I start the Eclipse. Unfortunately when I add "org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.finder" to the dependecies and export it again, the plug-in I get is not loaded by Eclipse when I start it. I don't get any error during the export process. So what can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: So the plugin was working fine and then you added another dependency? Why? It obviously wasn't required. You should keep dependencies to a minimum.

Comment: Exactly. But it is required because I'd like to use SWTBot.

Comment: Then you install SWTbot, separately.

Comment: My plug-in uses SWTBot classes so I think it shall be added to the dependencies.

Comment: If your code do relies on SWTBot classes then your thinking is right, you should add swtbot as a dependency. But since the plugin is working anyway, you must have solved it some other way. I'm guessing you have imported the swtbot jars to your project.

Comment: You've right. So I installed SWTBot but my plug-in is still not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that not the same version of some plug-ins were in the Eclipse plugins folder which I added to dependecies of my plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

So the question then is why isn't the plugin loading; There are a couple of steps to see what happens. There are alot of answers that help with this. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777020/207764), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293725/207764) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097320/207764)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured out what the problem was.