# Why eclipse couldn't be launched? It shows error log in configuration

Tags: android, eclipse, launch

I am using eclipse 3.7.2 for developing Android applications ... every thing worked fine until I installed a new update for from help tab and also I installed Subversive plugin for code management.

The error is as following:

[image: Eclipse error window]

I opened the error file that mentioned in the above path but I couldn't guess what the missing file, the file contains something like the following:

```
     !SESSION 2012-08-14 11:23:27.945 -----------------------------------------------
     eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
     java.version=1.6.0_30
     java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
     BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
     Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
     Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

      !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
      !MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
      !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
      !MESSAGE Bundle  reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.300.v20110928-1505.jar was  not resolved.
      !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
      !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_[3.6.0,4.0.0).
      !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
      !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.compare.win32_1.0.200.I20110510-0800.jar was not resolved.
       !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.compare.win32 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
       !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
          !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
       !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.7.1.v20120104-1859.jar was not resolved.
       !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
       !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
       !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
       !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui_3.7.1.v20120425-0100.jar was not resolved.
        !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
        !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_0.0.0.
        !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-08-14 11:23:28.945
        !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications_0.9.1.v20120412-0100.jar was not resolved.



          ...etc etc
```

So does anybody can help with this?

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install the new plugin?

Comment: from help tab in eclipse "Install new software" and I put the url for the plugin which is "Subversive"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK if you don't want to reinstall(actually resetup seems more correct) the eclipse then download 
`org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.5.0.I20100907-0800.jar`
`org.eclipse.jface.text_3.7.2.v20111213-1208.jar`

```
org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar
```

and place them in `eclipse_installed_directory/plugins/` and enjoy ;)
Let me know if error is still coming

Comment: I did many solutions and the last one was yours and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Check the plugin `org.eclipse.jface`. It seems to be of an older version. The plugins complain because they require version 3.5+, or 3.6+.

You can use Eclipse plugin registry view to examine the plugin or the OSGI console. Check out an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777020/207764) I did earlier for a similar question for more details on the console.

Comment: Thank you but I didn't understand it well ... I am not able to launch eclipse at all ... I don't want to reinstall it again.