# Installing Eclipse RCP Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application that I would like to install a plugin into. I know the plugin works with the application, and with older versions of the application I could just drop the plugin JAR into plugins/ folder and it would be available next time I loaded the application.

However, with the current version, the JAR doesn't seem to get picked up when I put it in the plugins/ folder. I've tried running the application with the --clean flag, but that doesn't help.

How do I tell the application that I want to install the plugin?

**Update:** Got it working by adding the plugin to the config.ini - I've not needed to do that before, previously it would just be picked up when I placed it in the plugins/ folder. Is there a configuration option that disables the detection of new plugins from the plugins/ folder?

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: Dropping it into the plugins folder should still be enough, there must be something else preventing the plugin from starting. Check the error log ('workspace/.metadata/.log')

Comment: Eclipse RCP version is 3.8.2 I think.

Nope, nothing in the logs - is there some configuration option that could have been enabled that would stop the latest version of the application picking up new plugins?

Comment: Try creating a catalog /eclipse/dropins and adding it there.

Comment: Try this trick I wrote about in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769730/cant-get-eclipse-to-recognize-my-plugin/7777020#7777020

Comment: The dropins suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Fredrik, it's not Eclipse but rather an Eclipse RCP application. I can find a console, but I can't find anything relating to an OSGi console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by adding the plugin to the config.ini - I've not needed to do that before, previously it would just be picked up when I placed it in the plugins/ folder. Is there a configuration option that disables the detection of new plugins from the plugins/ folder?

Answer (score 2):

@Fredrik basically says it: You need to put the plugin in the "dropins" folder, the sister directory to the plugins directory.  Then restart.  I usually run eclipse -clean just to be safe.  If there's a problem with the plugin, you will need to using the p2 debugger as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12480978/2295812