# Eclipse plugin does not work on some computer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've made an eclipse plugin but for some reason it does not seem to work on some computer. By not work I mean that eclipse says that the plugin is installed but none of the menu contributions show up.
Since the computer is not mine what would be the best way to figure out why does it not work?
Is there any app that could give me a log of some kind?

Simar

Comment: Your own app should be logging any errors to the Eclipse error log.  The Eclipse error log is located at (workspace)/.metadata/.log

Answer (score 0):

`Installed` means the plugin has been found, but there are some dependencies unsolved that prevents it from launching. You want it to be `resolved` or `active`

Look at [Dude, where's my bundle](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle) for more information on plugins and their different states. Install the Eclipse plugin development functionality to get plugin registry view, then you can diagnose your plugin. Or follow my advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777020/207764) and use the osgi console to diagnose it. 
The error or workspace log could also give some information regarding why the plugin wont start.